# Linker syntax : Linker does not use all of the linkers's flag during the linking

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, linker-flags

I have study makefile projec. I am using the gnu gcc and as linker, I use the gcc with the following argument:

> linkerCmdLine=$(exe) -Wl,--start-group -nostdlib -Map=test_mapfile.map -l:libc.a -l:libgcc.a -l:libm.a -Wl,--end-group -o $(output)

During the linking process, the linker does not use all of this flags:
The flag `-Map=test_mapfile.map` is not used.

Why??

There is a project settings file and in this one is also stored the linker settings.

> \u201ClinkerCmdLine\=$(exe) -Wl, --start-group -nostdlib -Map\=./99_output/PUZ_GPF.map --gc-sections -l\:libc.a -l\:libgcc.a -l\:libm.a -Wl,--end-group -o $(output)\u201D

How must I store the settings correct?

Edited:

With the the map file works fine, but I have actually problem with the linker file. I use only the following flag:

"linkerCmdLine=$(exe) -Wl, --script=C:/workspace/test_project/test_linker_file.ld -static -o $(output)”

I get this error in the console window:

arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '--script=C:/workspace/test_project/test_linker_file.ld'

I don't understand why, because the map file and the .ld file belong to the linker flags.

Answer (score 3):

The `-Wl,` prefix only passes the current argument, with commas separating linker arguments. So in order to pass `-z defs`, you would use `-Wl,-z,defs`.

This mechanism only works for true flags, i.e. when the position in the command line is irrelevant. The `-l` parameters are not flags, and the gcc compiler driver collects them into a separate list and passes them in a single block.

So this technique doesn't work for the exact commandline you want. On the other hand, the `-nostdlib` inhibits the `-lc -lgcc -lm` that would be the default.

Normally there is a provision in the gcc specs (the script for the compiler driver) to use `--start-group` and `--end-group` around the standard libraries when linking statically (which appears to be what you want to do).

So I think that

```
linkerCmdLine=$(exe) -Wl,-Map=test_mapfile.map -static -o $(output)
```

should work for your case.